# RF signal amplifier

Tags: rf, signal

I bought a tado smart thermostat but it has very bad signal.  the transceiver often loses connection with the controls fitted to the radiators.  i have tried various ways of pointing / positioning / angling it but the signal never reaches all thermostats.

It uses a 868 MHz frequency.

Is it possible to buy a signal booster?  I have seen some online e.g.: https://www.archiexpo.com/prod/eberle-controls/product-53224-1278761.html which is from a different system.

Would these work automatically to boost the signals?  Is there anything I would need to do to make sure it is working / boosting the right signal?

Any other advice welcome.

Comment: You will have to ask Tado if such a device exists and if the product from your link will work. Since we nor Tado has any idea how that signal booster works the answer is probably **no, we cannot guarantee that this will work**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, repeaters, especially in the radio world, do not just repeat anything they hear which just happens to be in the right frequency.

In most cases, they need to actually understand the signal they need to repeat (at least at the lower levels) before regenerating it for retransmission. In some circumstances it goes further as the repeater needs to actually actively negotiate with neighbouring nodes so traffic is correctly routed, de duplicated, etc.

So it’s quite unlikely you’ll be able to use a repeater from a different brand just because it’s in the right frequency band. It needs to use the same protocols as your devices. It is quite possible it could work if they are indeed compatible, but we lack information to know whether this is the case.

Comment: Thanks jcaron - that's what I needed. A followup question - if I know the protocol, would a generic repeater that uses that protocol work? Or is there some special restriction / band that devices have?   I found that "tado° devices communicate via radio at 868 MHz using the IPv6 enabled “6LoWPAN” protocol"

Comment: That's very specific to each protocol and/or manufacturer. There may be specific implementation details which are not 100% standard, or there may be private security keys specific to the manufacturer, for instance. I'm not familiar enough with 6LoWPAN to tell you whether this is likely or not in this instance. Have you tried asking the manufacturer?